# variables with same content are not equal .... why?

Tags: javascript

Why do i receive  false if both variables have equal content?

```
function A() { return {k:'k'}; }
function B() { return {k:'k'}; }

var a = new A;
var b = new B;

 var s='';

for (prop in a) {
   if (typeof a[prop] != "function") {
       s += "a[" + prop + "] = " + a[prop] + "; ";
   }
}
alert(s);


for (prop in b) {
   if (typeof b[prop] != "function") {
       s += "b[" + prop + "] = " + b[prop] + "; ";
   }
}
alert(s);


alert( a == b ); // false?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wZjPg/

same happens even if i assign both a and b same function

```
var obj = {};

function A() { return {k:'k'}; }

var a = new A;
var b = new A;

alert( a == b ); // false?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3rzrR/

and same here

```
k={zor:1};
b={zor:1};

alert(k==b); //false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5v8BJ/

Comment: You're comparing objects, not properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because objects are compared by reference.

```
[] === []; // false
```

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators,

> If **both operands are objects**, then JavaScript compares internal
>   references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in
>   memory.

Comment: so i must manually check all properties?

Comment: @Sol **You should define what you mean when you consider that two objects are the same, and test that**. For example, you could check if they have same properties (own / own+inherited), and if the properties are objects you must decide too if you will compare them using your own definition or by reference.